# MariaDB handling composite unique indexes that are foreign keys at the same time

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, unique-constraint

I have a possible issue with how MariaDB (and probably MySQL) handles composite unique indexes that are also foreign keys. Not sure if that is by design and if it is, why does it work like that.

I have a table called action_contact. It has a foreign key action_id to the 'action' table and contact_id to the 'contact' table. Both are unsigned bigint columns. I need these two fields to be unique indexes as well. If I don't add the unique index, both fields are also indexes in the database by default, which is fine. But, once I add the unique composite index (action_id, contact_id) - it’s added in the database, but the normal index for contact_id is still present and the normal index for action_id is removed. The foreign keys are still present, as they should. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: You need to show us the exact DDL statement(s) for the table and its indexes if you expect a meaningful answer.

Comment: It would have been clearer to get the full `CREATE TABLE` and subsequent SQL commands in code blocks, but the question had enough information to be be understood and respond to it, I humbly believe.

Comment: An index on `(a, b)` can speed up searches for `a` only, but not for `b` only.

Comment: Please  include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Multiple indexes over the same columns are allowed, but deprecated (as it is redundant- there is almost nothing that the non-unique key can do that the unique index cannot), and may error out in the future (although probably not for different index types like this case).

My suggestion, to prevent confusion, is to just create the unique index (or any explicit index that is adequate with a custom name) from the beginning. I agree with you, that this could be confusing, so looking at the manual is always a great idea, and I believe the current implementation make sense from a compromise between control and optimization perspective. :-)

Comment: I suppose it should be "Multiple indexes over the same *columns* is allowed"

Comment: unique composite index on 'action_id, contact_id' cannot be used for index_merge/intersection (unlike index on just action_id it may require sort_intersection) with index on third column if contact_id is not presented in where conditions.

Comment: Fair corrections, updated.

Comment: "Index merge intersection" can always(?) be improved upon by a composite `INDEX` with all the indicated columns.